# How to translate a data from database using ng2-translate in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-translate, ng2-translate

need translate data from database using ng2-translate in angular without using JSON file or can we translate text using ng2-translate..

I tried by following code to translate text
`this.translate.get("SPANISH") .subscribe((data: string) => { this.value= data; });`

Please guide me ..

Comment: what version of Angular?

Comment: @Nate T angular 5

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom translation loader:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-translate#write--use-your-own-loader

That also means all translations will be loaded at once. But if there is a lot of data to translate, it's better to use other approach to translate the data (for example - pass the desired language in the URL  `?lang=en` and return the data translated already).

Comment: in which url need to translate ?can you give some example plz.

Comment: It's not clear from the question which issue exactly we should solve. So far I have 2 assumptions: 1st - keep translation data in database instead of json file. 2nd - have user data translated into a multiple languages. Could you give more details please?

Comment: i try to add my site with multiple langauage(spanish,english)..in my site i am having multiple pages,in that most of the grid values are loaded from the databases .how can i convert those things into other langauage..

Comment: Do you expect to translate the data automatically, like the GoogleTranslate service does?

Comment: yes,looking to translate the data automatically when page loads

Comment: FYI I also tried google translate api service in that i faced lots of issue like (button events are not working after translate)

Comment: 'ng2-translate' is working with multi-language data which should be translated in advance.

Comment: now i am using that,can you please guide me to proceed futhur,i almost complete all static pages by created json files,but for dynamic pages?